# visual studio generate .net dll files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exe

im building an app using c# (not my first. other projects i dont have this problem). this one i included nuget package json

the problem that VS generates too many .dll files in my bin/debug folder (with exe). i don't want these dll files but it seems like the exe doesn't run without them (i coppied the exe to another path and run it)

[image]

when i search on the internet all the details about merging using some merge tool but my problem is related VisualStudio in the setting i believe?

[image]

Comment: ""nuget package json*" -- which package?

Comment: ilmerge can do many things, but whats so bad about the DLLs?

Comment: It seems all dependent DLLs are copied to the output folder. this should be the difference from your previous projects.

Comment: Microsoft System.json @canton7

Comment: why VS is not implementing them into EXE like other projects? @ilkerkaran

Comment: @BugFinder too many are annoying to copy or give them to some one.. love to see simple program im building as one exe file

Comment: Have you gone through all your projects to remove any dll references that aren't actually used in your code? In principle any standard dlls should already be available on a computer that has the right version of .NET installed, so you shouldn't need to include the standard ones. That leaves any non-Microsoft or non-standard dlls that you might want to embed in your executable, but that's going to [take some work](http://adamthetech.com/2011/06/embed-dll-files-within-an-exe-c-sharp-winforms/)

Comment: "why VS is not implementing them into EXE"? Because their not code you wrote, they contain code written by others, already compiled into dlls. In order to include them into the exe, visual studio will have to decompile each DLL and then recompile it back into the EXE. That can open a door for all kind of problems, not to mention the load on your machine and the time it would add to the compilation process.

Comment: What DLLs are being copied into the output folder?

Comment: Make sure you target .NET 4.7.2 (right-click project -> properties -> Target framework). System.Json targets .NET Standard 2.0, but .NET Framework versions below 4.7.2 only have partial support for .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: @BugFinder i've included one picture showing the dll names in the output folder .. not all but i gives indication of the problem?

Comment: @Hasanalattar you may have but its not a link I can view, its showing as broken for me

Comment: @canton7 thank you i downloaded .NET 4.7.2 and now i have only System.JSON.dll which is fine. i dont know how to mark this as solved problem..

Comment: I've added an answer, which you can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you include a library which targets .NET Standard 1.5 or higher, from a project which targets .NET Framework 4.7.1 or lower.

The [.NET Platform Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) table hints at this: it claims that .NET Framework 4.6.1 supports .NET Standard 1.5 or higher, but there's a footnote:

> The versions listed here represent the rules that NuGet uses to determine whether a given .NET Standard library is applicable. While NuGet considers .NET Framework 4.6.1 as supporting .NET Standard 1.5 through 2.0, there are several issues with consuming .NET Standard libraries that were built for those versions from .NET Framework 4.6.1 projects. For .NET Framework projects that need to use such libraries, we recommend that you upgrade the project to target .NET Framework 4.7.2 or higher.

One of these issues is that you'll get a lot of extra DLLs, apparently because .NET Framework 4.6.1 only has partial support for .NET Standard 1.5.

The solution is for your project to target .NET Framework 4.7.2, or .NET Core.